# Setting up two-way ssl with Certificate authority

Tags: java, ssl, https, jetty

I've set up a jetty (9.2.0.M1) hosted application.

I've configured jetty to run a two-way SSL with the following setup:

```
 server.keystore - contains server private key and is self signed.
 server.truststore - contains clients certs that should be trusted.
```

This is working and when I hit `https://127.0.0.1` in my browser where I have a valid certificate it works.

I'm now trying to do this without my own signed certificate. To do this I set up a DNS (lets say exampleDNS.com and created a certificate sign request server.csr that I sent to the CA-vendor.

I've got a mail back with the certificate to use and I included that into the server.keystore.

However: when I now hit `https://exampleDNS.com` the server still present the self signed certificate instead of validating it by the CA.

I'm probably missing something here but I can't really understand what I'm doing wrong.

> Do I need to include root certificate of the specific CA-vendor into keystore/truststore?

Comment: Have you used the same private key for cert request?

Comment: Thank you for a fast reply, I did used keytool to generate the csr from my server.keystore. So yes it should be the same private key

Comment: I believe you should import CA certificate to your keystore first. I did. I think it should not even allow you to import signed by CA certificate without first importing CA cert, as a chain can't be built.

Comment: The CA cert was imported to the keystore without any problem without having the CA certificate in my keystore. I will try to add the CA cert to my keystore aswell

Comment: I've added the certificate to the truststore but no different -.- I'm trying to set this up using thawte as CA-vendor.

Comment: Does you browser have your CA in a trusted list? Otherwise it wouldn't be able to check cert validity

Comment: I use google chrome and the root certificate can be found under 'settings-> advance -> show certificates'

Comment: The certificate that is shown says it is issued by myself; exampleDNS.com and to myself. Is it possible that the application don't load the cert I added from the .csr request that I got from thwate? (It is found in the keystore tho: keytool -list -v -keystore keystore

Comment: Did you configured certAlias in Jetty? It chooses certificate to use, I think. Never tried 2 or more certs in keystore setup. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL

Comment: I'm also on a network that uses a DNS -> so when I hit the https://exampleDNS.com it goes to the DNS and then back into my local network can this cause an issue?? (i.e. everything is local)

Comment: should the certalias point to the alias that points to the .csr entry in my keystore??

Comment: It's about alias of certificate I believe. One you imported as keytool -importcert -v -alias server_cert <-

Comment: When I do this and hit the url : I get the answer SSL: connectionerror,  "it could be because the server require a clientcertificate that you dont have"

Comment: Well, don't know. You should find a way to look at certificate presented by server. Maybe if just can't verify hostname. I'm not shure.

Comment: I ran with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl. I get the following:

found key: exampleDNS.com:
Chain[0] -> points to my own private key and its setup.
........
Adding as trusted cert: 
My own private cert,RooT thawte, Trial Thawte, Thawte csr.

----

Comment: So does your certAlias point to thawte csr alias? (that is signed certificate I guess)? You can list it like this: keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks

Comment: When I hit the dns it says: "fatal: engine already closed. no chiper suits in commmon"

Comment: Isn't csr a sign request? It should not be there, probably. You sure you imported signed certificate? What files have you got? It should be a chain of CA certificates (or single one) and your personal signed certificate. How many you got? If Trial Thawte is you personal certificate try pointing to it

Comment: I've registrated a Thawte free trial, got an email from them with three certificates i.e. three 
--bigin certi-- ENCRYPTEDDATA ---end cert --
-Thawte trial SSL certificate
-Thawte Trial Secure Server Intermediate CA
-Thawte Test CA Root certificate

I've saved text into tree files (Thawte Test CA Root certificate, Thawte Trial Secure Server Intermediate CA, Thawte trial SSL certificate) and imported them by using keytools

Comment: keytool -import -alias ThawteTrialSecureServer -keystore keystore -trustcacerts -file "Thawte Trial Secure Server Intermediate CA" x3

Comment: It is not the .csr I have in the keystore it is the response from Thawte

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would try to repeat process one more time. And make sure you import Root cert first, Intermediate second and trial last. And last one should have the same alias as you used when created private key. I probably can't suggest anything else, sorry.

Comment: Big thanks for your help, when I get some more time I will repeat the process. One thing that you mention is that I should use the same alias as I used when I created the private key - that is something I know I have not done. 

I will come back when I've tried this